# Set-AzureVNetGatewayKey cmdlet does not exist in Azure PowerShell

Tags: vpn, azure, site-to-site-vpn

**Background**
I am attempting to link up multiple VNets with one another in Azure. To do this I am following this tutorial:

[VNet-to-VNet: Connecting Virtual Networks in Azure across Different Regions](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/06/17/vnet-to-vnet-connecting-virtual-networks-in-azure-across-different-regions/)

I also found another reference that does about the same:

[Azure VNET to VNET VPN, across regions and data centers: not so complicated](http://marius-zaharia.blogspot.fr/2014/06/azure-vnet-to-vnet-vpn-across-regions.html)

**Problem**
Both tutorials state that I have to set a gateway key through the cmdlet 'Set-AzureVNetGatewayKey'. This however seems to be a non-existant cmdlet. Everything was successful till this point.

```
PS C:\> Set-AzureVNetGatewayKey -VNetName NETONE-LocalNetworkSiteName NETONE SharedKey  *********
Set-AzureVNetGatewayKey : The term 'Set-AzureVNetGatewayKey' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I am also unable to find the said command in the Azure Cmdlet Reference

Does anyone know of an alternative way???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

update your azure powershell installation. its a new cmdlet.

Comment: which version contains the cmdlet?

Comment: Does it matter? Just grab the latest.

Comment: Versions aside - After downloading the latest version of Azure PowerShell through Web Platform Installer I now can use the said cmdlet! Hooray! Thank you for your swift answer!